# Ratings stars CSS (hover position change)

Tags: html, css, rating

I tried ratings stars for my webpage.But yellow star always starts on the right when I selected stars .

I don't want to change my "input id ranking"

How I start yellow star from left? (input id always  will start with 1)

example:  [my project example](http://cssdeck.com/labs/full/1kdysh6x)

```css
@import url(http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css);

            fieldset, label { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
            body{ margin: 20px; }
            h1 { font-size: 1.5em; margin: 10px; }

            .rating { 
                border: none;
                float: left;
            }

            .rating > input { display: none; } 
            .rating > label:before { 
                margin: 5px;
                font-size: 1.25em;
                font-family: FontAwesome;
                display: inline-block;
                content: "\f005";
            }

            .rating > .half:before { 
                content: "\f089";
                position: absolute;
            }

            .rating > label { 
                color: #ddd; 
            }

            .rating > input:checked ~ label, 
            .rating:not(:checked) > label:hover,  
            .rating:not(:checked) > label:hover ~ label { color: #FFD700;  }

            .rating > input:checked + label:hover, 
            .rating > input:checked ~ label:hover,
            .rating > label:hover ~ input:checked ~ label, 
            .rating > input:checked ~ label:hover ~ label { color: #FFED85;  }
```

```html
     <fieldset class="rating">
                    <input class="stars" type="radio" id="star1" name="rating" value="1" />
                        <label class = "full" for="star1" title="Sucks big time - 1 star">1</label>
                        <input class="stars" type="radio" id="star2" name="rating" value="2" />
                        <label class = "full" for="star2" title="Kinda bad - 2 stars">2</label>
                        <input class="stars" type="radio" id="star3" name="rating" value="3" />
                        <label class = "full" for="star3" title="Meh - 3 stars">3</label>
                        <input class="stars" type="radio" id="star4" name="rating" value="4" />
                        <label class = "full" for="star4" title="Pretty good - 4 stars">4</label>
                        <input class="stars" type="radio" id="star5" name="rating" value="5" />
                        <label class = "full" for="star5" title="Awesome - 5 stars">5</label>
                
                    </fieldset>
```

Comment: Does it help if you add this style? `.rating { direction: rtl;  }` then switch the numbers accordingly?

Comment: Yes, I did but the problem was not solved

Comment: Other examples, input id start 5 -4-3-2-1.But I want to input id start 1-2-3-4-5

Comment: _But I want to ..._ Is this a requirement or just you wanting it that way because it looks better and makes more sense? Because here is a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/exy9vrnj/) of what I was talking about.

Comment: yes this is requirement, because my php code  automatically lineup this "input id" , if I change label value number, label and input doesn't match

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can order your input from 5 to 1 instead of the reverse.

Add this to css:

```
.rating > label{float:right}
```

```css
            /****** Rating Starts *****/
            @import url(http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css);

            fieldset, label { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
            body{ margin: 20px; }
            h1 { font-size: 1.5em; margin: 10px; }

            .rating { 
                border: none;
                float: left;
            }

            .rating > input { display: none; } 
            .rating > label:before { 
                margin: 5px;
                font-size: 1.25em;
                font-family: FontAwesome;
                display: inline-block;
                content: "\f005";
            }

            .rating > .half:before { 
                content: "\f089";
                position: absolute;
            }

            .rating > label { 
                color: #ddd; 
            }

            .rating > input:checked ~ label, 
            .rating:not(:checked) > label:hover,  
            .rating:not(:checked) > label:hover ~ label { color: #FFD700;  }

            .rating > input:checked + label:hover, 
            .rating > input:checked ~ label:hover,
            .rating > label:hover ~ input:checked ~ label, 
            .rating > input:checked ~ label:hover ~ label { color: #FFED85;  }     

    .rating > label{float:right}
```

```html
     <fieldset class="rating">
     
                             <input class="stars" type="radio" id="star5" name="rating" value="5" />
                        <label class = "full" for="star5" title="Awesome - 5 stars">5</label>
                                        <input class="stars" type="radio" id="star4" name="rating" value="4" />
                        <label class = "full" for="star4" title="Pretty good - 4 stars">4</label>
                                                <input class="stars" type="radio" id="star3" name="rating" value="3" />
                        <label class = "full" for="star3" title="Meh - 3 stars">3</label>
                        <input class="stars" type="radio" id="star2" name="rating" value="2" />
                        <label class = "full" for="star2" title="Kinda bad - 2 stars">2</label>




                    <input class="stars" type="radio" id="star1" name="rating" value="1" />
                        <label class = "full" for="star1" title="Sucks big time - 1 star">1</label>
                    </fieldset>
```

Comment: If I add this code, that sort of thing happens, "5-4-3-2-1"  But I want to "1-2-3-4-5" and star will be start from left

Comment: @shinemagin so you just don't know how to loop through your array in reverse order?

Comment: thank you for help, Solved problem. I changed my php codes